# libgdx, how to check collision of randomly generated actors?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have two groups of randomly generated actors, one is bullets second is enemies. And as of now I have no idea how to check collision of randomly genrated actors and remove the overlaped actors. I'm newby.

At least provide some pseudocode!
Thanx in advance!!!

Comment: possibly better suited to gamedev.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: thanx for advise, just after your comment I posted it there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Using a physics engine**

   Libgdx has [built-in support](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Physics) for following.

   1. [Box2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d) for 2D physics
   2. [Bullet](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Bullet-physics) for 3D physics.

   Physics engine can handle collision detection and you can provide callbacks to specify what to do when a collision occurs.
   You can find many tutorials on the internet.

---

2. **Implement collision yourself**

   It is a bit work but may be suitable for small applications.

   1. You will have to perform a n^2 intersection check for all objects in each frame.
   2. For this, you will have to write intersection test logic for all your shape pairs.
   3. Then you can deal with detected collisions as per your wish.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.